# Searching XML doc for specific path using Nokogiri and changing it

Tags: ruby, xml, cucumber, nokogiri

Searching XML doc for specific path using Nokogiri and changing it (using Cucumber in front)

I want to search a XML document for a specific path and then change it to something else. This is a relevant portion of the XML:

```
<Root>
 <Application>   
  <Connections>
   <AutoAccept>true</AutoAccept>
  <AllowDomains/>
  </Connections>
  <Streams>
   <StreamType>default</StreamType>
    <StorageDir>/C:/blah/flash/</StorageDir>
```

I want to change the "/C:/blah/flash/" to another value. This is what I have code-wise:

```
Given(/^Update the Apreso configuration file$/) do 
  xmldoc = Nokogiri::XML(DATA['DATA_WOWZA1'])
  xmldoc.search("/Root/Application/Streams/StorageDir").each do |node|
  node.content = "Newpath"
 end

 puts xmldoc.to_xml
end
```

The "DATA_WOWZA1" is the path of the XML file that I'm passing through a YAML file. When I run the code it passes but the XML file doesn't reflect the change, thoughts?

Comment: Are you searching for empty string, or is it just a dummy code?

Comment: Ahmad, that was a type, thanks bro. Searching for a path, see code above.

Comment: So what's wrong with this XPath? It works fine on my end; node changes are reflected properly. What version of nokogiri are you using?

Comment: How many `StorageDir` nodes are there in the XML? One, or many? If only one, then you're doing it the hard way.

Comment: ^One, how to refactor to make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `Nokogiri::XML` a string of XML, not a filepath string. Try:

```
xmldoc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read DATA['DATA_WOWZA1'])
```

It doesn't make sense, though, that you are getting the original XML output. Are you sure your test is outputting XML?

If you want to save the file in place, you'll need to do something like:

```
File.open(DATA['DATA_WOWZA1'], 'w') { |f| f.puts xmldoc.to_xml }
```

Comment: This works, the output in terminal shows the changes but the file doesn't reflect the change, do I need to save the file?

Comment: Added example of saving the file in place.

Comment: I just tried:
    File.open(DATA['DATA_WOWZA1'],'w') {|f| xmldoc.write_xml_to f}
and saw your comment, thanks kardeiz! It works :)

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one `StorageDir` node, then you're working too hard:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<Root>
 <Application>   
  <Connections>
   <AutoAccept>true</AutoAccept>
  <AllowDomains/>
  </Connections>
  <Streams>
   <StreamType>default</StreamType>
    <StorageDir>/C:/blah/flash/</StorageDir>
  </Streams>
  </Application>
  </Root>
EOT

doc.at('StorageDir').content = 'd:/path/to/foo'
puts doc.to_xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <Root>
# >>  <Application>   
# >>   <Connections>
# >>    <AutoAccept>true</AutoAccept>
# >>   <AllowDomains/>
# >>   </Connections>
# >>   <Streams>
# >>    <StreamType>default</StreamType>
# >>     <StorageDir>d:/path/to/foo</StorageDir>
# >>   </Streams>
# >>   </Application>
# >>   </Root>
```

Overwriting the original file is easily done too. This is untested, but looks 'bout right:

```
XML_FILE = 'path/to/xml'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(XML_FILE, 'r'))
doc.at('StorageDir').content = 'd:/path/to/foo'
File.write("#{ XML_FILE }.new", doc.to_xml)
```

Note, I'm not overwriting the original file, I'm writing to a new file. If something went wrong with the code, such as modifying the wrong node, this would preserve the old file instead of destroy its contents.

In production systems, you'd want to write to a new file, then rename the old one to something safe, rename the new one to the name of the old one, and then optionally delete the old one once you're sure everything is working correctly. By doing that you're OK if something goes wrong.